# Is DiffUtil.Callback with nested arraylist possible

Tags: java, android

I have a question about the DiffUtil.Callback class in Android which is used to compute the differences between two lists efficiently. It is often used in combination with the RecyclerView.
In all examples I have found, they use lists like

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> newList;
ArrayList<CustomObject> oldList;

// the other methods that need to be overridden
// e.g. getOldListSize(), getNewListSize() etc.
```

My question is: Is it possible to write the DiffUtil.Callback with a list of lists like the following ...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>> oldList;
ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>> newList;
```

Is is possible ? If not, why not. If yes, how would the class extending DiffUtil.Callback would look like ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? After all `<ArrayList<CustomObject>>` is just another type of object.
You just have to figure out how you want to check whether the new and old objects have changed or are the same.
Now a question for you: why do you need to have a `List` inside another `List` in the first place?
Also you're asking for code, but you haven't shown any effort in writing your own code. Show us some code and I'll do my best to help correct it if it's not working :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate the nested list in areItemsTheSame and areContentsTheSame methods. If any of the item has changed return false.

```
class FilterDiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FilterUIModel>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: FilterUIModel, newItem: FilterUIModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem.name == newItem.name
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: FilterUIModel, newItem: FilterUIModel): Boolean {
        val size = oldItem.filterDataUiModel?.size ?: 0
        for (index in 0 until size) {
            if(oldItem.filterDataUiModel?.get(index) != newItem.filterDataUiModel?.get(index))
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```